# Selenium VBA Unable to Click Checkbox

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium and Chrome, I'm attempting to check a box located within a table. The table contains 2 checkboxes but they act as radio buttons, in that if I click one, the other will uncheck.

I've tried a variety of methods, which include the following:

```
Const CHECKED_STATE As String = "Ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"    
findElementByClassName("ag-selection-checkbox").fireEvent("CHECKED_STATE")

findElementbyXPath("//span[@class=ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked'])[1]").Click

findElementbyXPath(".//div[@class='ag-body-container']").Click
```

I'm not sure how to click the checkbox when the HTML code doesn't even have a checkbox type or an Id.

The HTML reads:

```
    <span class="ag-icon-checkbox">
<span class = "ag-icon ag-icon checkbox-checked ag-hidden">
<span class = "ag-icon ag-icon checkbox-unchecked">
<span class = "ag-icon ag-icon checkbox-undeterminate ag-hidden"></span>
```

When I click on the checkbox, the unchecked and hidden lines of HTML will flip. So I'm guessing it's some sort of event that I have to trigger.

Comment: Do you need to toggle between them? Or only ever need to select the unchecked one?

Comment: Only need to select the unchecked @QHarr.

Answer (score 0):

The following, depending on the rest of the html, should work to select the unchecked item and thereby toggle off the other item. It targets the class `checkbox-unchecked`:

```
driver.FindElementByCss(".ag-icon-checkbox .checkbox-unchecked").click
```

Comment: I tried both with "ag-icon-checkbox" and "ag-icon ag-icon checkbox-unchecked" and it's throwing a "NoSuchElementError Element not found for Css=ag-selection-checkbox".

Comment: Is your element inside a parent frame/iframe tag?

Comment: yes, it appears so since I can see <iframe title="Application content" class... That's an option I'm looking into since I just found a question related to reCaptcha stating that I have to make the element clickable. This isn't a reCaptcha. It's just a table.

Comment: you need to SwitchTo that iframe first

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out now. I'm unsure of what the iframe name is.

Comment: you can possibly refer to it by its title instead `FindElementByCss("[title='Application content']")`